# Django select_related not retrieving subclassed models

Tags: django

I have four models:

```
Task(models.Model):
    fields...
BasicImage(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    fields...

VisImage(BasicImage):
    fields...

IRImage(BasicImage):
    fields...
```

Later I have code that does the following:

```
task = Task.objects.get()
basicimages = task.basicimage_set.select_related().all()
imageset1 = basicimages.filter(filter=1)
imageset2 = basicimages.filter(filter=2)
```

and in a template, I end up displaying the information like so:

```
{% for i in imageset1 %}
    {{ i.visimage.field }}
{% endfor %}

{% for i in imageset2 %}
    {{ i.irimage.field %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, according to the Django Debug toolbar (and the obvious lag), Django is still requerying for each .visimage and .irimage object.  How come select_related isn't taking care of this?

Answer (score 1):

model inheritance adds a implicit one-to-one field on the subclass model. as much as i know, select_related doesn't work for reverse relations.

Comment: It does for One-To-One fields https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7270#comment:66

Comment: ahhh... my bad.. please downvot eme